# Making a Numpy Operation Vectorised

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Long story short, I'm applying a function onto multiple different time intervals and then storing the resulting arrays at different indexs in an ndarray. Presently, I'm doing this by using the a `for` loop with the numpy equivalent of the `enumerate` function. As I understand it, this eliminates the major advantage of numpy: vectorisation. Is this a particular way my rountine could be implemented that retains this advantage?

Here is my code:

Most of is working parts for the function `psi_t`

```
import numpy as np

# Number of Walks and Number of Positions

N = 100
P = 2*N +1

hopping_rate = 0.5


psi_t0 = np.zeros(P)
psi_t0[N] = 1

#creates the line upon which the particle moves
#index N is the central position

def hamiltonian(line_length, hopping_rate):
    '''
    creates the simple non time dependent hamiltonian for H = γA
    where A is the adjancency matrix
    '''
    return hopping_rate * line_adjacency_matrix(line_length)


def measurement_operator(positions,finished_quantum_state):
    '''
    Converts the finished quantum state into an array of probabilities for
    being in each position.

    Uses the measurement operator from Susan Blog
    https://susan-stepney.blogspot.com/2014/02/mathjax.html

    Improved on by this guy
    https://github.com/Driminary/python-randomwalk-project/blob/master/quantum-2D.py

    Apart from the fact that the measurement operator drops the extra dimensions of the spin space,
    which isn't present in the continuous walk.


    '''
    probabilities = np.empty(P)

    #M_hat = np.zeros((2*P,2*P,2*P))

    for k in range(P):
        posn = np.zeros(P)  # values of positions to nought ..
        posn[k] = 1 #except for the value we're interested in
        #M_hat = np.kron(np.outer(posn,posn)) #perform measurement at the current pos
        M_hat = np.outer(posn,posn)
        proj = M_hat.dot(finished_quantum_state) #find the state the system is in
        probabilities[k] = proj.dot(proj.conjugate()).real  #Calculate Prob of Particle being there

    return probabilities


def psi_t(initial_wave_function,positions,hopping_rate,time):
    '''
    Acts upon the initial state to give the 'position' of the quantum particle at time t. Applies the measurement operator
    to return the probability of being at any position at time t.
    '''

    psi_t = np.matmul((LA.expm(-1j*hamiltonian(positions,hopping_rate)*time)),initial_wave_function) #state after the continuous walk after time evolution

    probablities =  measurement_operator(P, psi_t)

    return probablities


time_evolution = 150  #how many 'seconds' the wavefunction is evolved for 

time_interval = 0.5 

number_of_intervals =int(time_evolution /  time_interval )


number_of_positions = P
probabilities_at_t  =np.ndarray((number_of_intervals,number_of_positions))  #creates the empty ndarray  ready for the probabilites at time t

array_of_times = np.linspace(0,time_evolution,number_of_intervals) #produces the individual times at which psi_t is calculated, 



for idx,time in np.ndenumerate(array_of_times):
    probabilities_at_t[idx] = psi_t(psi_t0,P,hopping_rate,time)  #the array probabillites_at_t is filled at index idx with the array of probabilities produced by psi_t. 
#This is the step I am trying to vectorise
```

The function `psi_t` is called on a `for` loop to act on each of the `time`(s) in `array_of_times` individually. Is there way where `psi_t` could act on the array `array_of_times` like one can do `x**2` for the array `x`? Can it be done in one fell swoop?

P.S Eagle Eyed Overflowers will note that within the `measurement_operator` there is a `for` loop anyway. I don't think there's a way to get rid of this however !

Comment: I think that most of the functions can be vectorized here, actually (even `measurement operator` using `tensordot/einsum`). Trying to get this to run but not sure what `LA` is inside the function `psi_t`. Is that a library that you haven't imported?

Comment: Ah, it's  the linear algebra module from scipy, used to exponentiate the matrix !

Comment: If you could please post a full working code here, I could try taking a look to make it vectorized. `line_adjacency_matrix` is also an undefined function in the code.

Comment: Also, `positions` are being passed into the function `measurement_operator`, but it's not being used there. Only `finished_quantum_state` is being used. I am not sure why it's being passed in then

Answer (score 1):

Question is not really reproducible because some of the functions that are being called are missing but here is my vectorised implementation of `measurement_operator`. This is with the assumption that `finished_quantum_state` has a shape of `(P, )` (Not sure if that's the case, because couldn't reproduce till that part) .

```
def measurement_operator_vectorized(positions, finished_quantum_state):

    M_hat = np.zeros((P, P, P))
    M_hat[np.arange(0, P), np.arange(0, P), np.arange(0, P)] = 1
    proj = np.tensordot(M_hat, finished_quantum_state, axes=((2), (0)))
    probabilities = (proj * proj.conjugate()).sum(axis=1).real

    return probabilities
```

Here is some benchmarkings -

```
P = 1000

a = np.random.rand(P)
b = np.random.rand(P)

%timeit c1 = measurement_operator(a, b)
%timeit c2 = measurement_operator_vectorized(a, b)

%memit c1 = measurement_operator(a, b)
%memit c2 = measurement_operator_vectorized(a, b)

print(np.allclose(c1, c2))
```

Gives -

```
1.18 s ± 46.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
308 ms ± 6.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
peak memory: 86.43 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
peak memory: 90.34 MiB, increment: 3.91 MiB
True
```

The vectorised version is faster is comparable memory usage for P~1000.
Note that for really high values of P, the memory usage will increase a lot for the vectorised version.

This isn't exactly what the OP asked for, but to vectorise the other loop, a more complete code would be helpful.

However, this benchmark is valid only if `finished_quantum_state` is real. For complex values the `tensordot` operation is very slow and inefficient (in memory)  so you might actually be better off with the non-vectorized version.

```
P = 1000

a = np.random.rand(P) + np.random.rand(P)*1j
b = np.random.rand(P) + np.random.rand(P)*1j

%timeit -n1 -r1 c1 = measurement_operator(a, b)
%timeit -n1 -r1 c2 = measurement_operator_vectorized(a, b)

%memit c1 = measurement_operator(a, b)
%memit c2 = measurement_operator_vectorized(a, b)

np.allclose(c1, c2)

2.97 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
3.49 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
peak memory: 102.69 MiB, increment: 0.03 MiB
peak memory: 15365.38 MiB, increment: 15262.69 MiB
```

However, if you really want the best performance, you are better off forgetting the physics details about measurement etc temporarily and just doing

```
def measurement_operator_fastest(positions, finished_quantum_state):
    return (finished_quantum_state * finished_quantum_state.conjugate()).real 

P = 1000

a = np.random.rand(P) + np.random.rand(P)*1j
b = np.random.rand(P) + np.random.rand(P)*1j

%timeit -n1 -r1 c1 = measurement_operator(a, b)
%timeit -n1 -r1 c2 = measurement_operator_vectorized(a, b)
%timeit -n1 -r1 c3 = measurement_operator_fastest(a, b)

%memit c1 = measurement_operator(a, b)
%memit c2 = measurement_operator_vectorized(a, b)
%memit c3 = measurement_operator_fastest(a, b)

print(np.allclose(c1, c2))
print(np.allclose(c1, c3))

2.87 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
3.48 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
16.6 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
peak memory: 102.70 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
peak memory: 15365.39 MiB, increment: 15262.69 MiB
peak memory: 102.69 MiB, increment: -0.01 MiB
True
True
```

By taking the inner product directly, you can make the function around 10^6 times faster. Of course that assumes the measurement operator as defined.